# Histogram plotting one column (string) with second column (int) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot, graph

I've got a dataset with several columns where I want to create a histogram outputting a string column to the x-axis and an int value to the y-axis.

Sample data:

```
100039241   lustalloverme   275 598 16123   0   28 Dec 2009 20:26:38 GMT    diamond lane ; *
100039367   A7madista   213 420 13849   0   28 Dec 2009 20:27:17 GMT    Dubai / London
100039585   MoetWitMedusa   349 373 10062   0   28 Dec 2009 20:28:22 GMT    NCAT/WishANiggah Woods
100042406   TheCameronApts  27  21  203 0   28 Dec 2009 20:41:59 GMT    Silver Spring, MD
100043628   AmeliaSparksx3  804 455 1679    0   28 Dec 2009 20:48:00 GMT    Mystic Falls, VA
100048228   AlainaPartlo12  2527    2541    20076   0   28 Dec 2009 21:10:44 GMT    
100049128   EliseSandstw12  2315    2197    13475   0   28 Dec 2009 21:15:15 GMT    
100049639   GloriaEdwards12 2691    2735    18788   0   28 Dec 2009 21:17:42 GMT    
100050202   Ebentwittes 193 1312    5396    0   28 Dec 2009 21:20:30 GMT    London, UK
```

If I try to use `df.plot( x='User Location', y='Follower Count', kind='hist')` it outputs  the same as df.plot.hist() which is:

[image: this]

When I try barcharts, it gives me an error of

```
ValueError: Where the $$$$ is !!!! 
                 ^ 
Expected end of text (at char 10), (line:1, col:11)
```

and

```
ValueError: 
Where the $$$$ is !!!!
          ^
Expected end of text (at char 10), (line:1, col:11)
```

This is not the first encounter of a space or a $, why does it expect end of text?

Anyone know how to properly do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you're not really looking for a histogram as much as a bar chart?

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are correct. I was looking for that initially, but after that didn't work I started looking for alternatives and got stuck in histograms

Answer (score 0):

if 'User Location' is unique, you may want bar plot

```
df.plot( x='User Location', y='Follower Count', kind='bar')
```

if one location has multi follower count,
i.e.
loc1, 10
loc1, 12
loc2, 20
loc2, 30

you can aggregate the data frame first

```
df.groupby('User_location').agg(sum)['Follower_Count'].plot.bar()
```

you can change sum in agg() to others like mean, max, min, etc.

Comment: It would be useful to point out that the OP was indeed not looking for a histogram as much as a bar chart.

Comment: Right, apparantly I was. I was working on this last week and tried to make a bar chart, which didn't work either, and tried switching to histogram, sorry about that. Anyway, when I try barcharts, it gives me an error of `ValueError: 
Where the $$$$ is !!!!
          ^
Expected end of text (at char 10), (line:1, col:11)` . This is not the first encounter of a space or a $, why does it expect end of text?

Comment: User Location has multiple followers, the 2nd option gives me the same error as the latter part in my (now edited) question, sadly

Comment: please give a minimum reproducible example.